# Galois group of splitting field of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $f$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and irreducible  over $\Bbb{Q}$. Let $p$ be a prime. Suppose $f(mod $ $p$) can be written down as a profuct of $r$ distict irreducible polynomials (over $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$) with degrees $d_1,...d_r$. Let $G$ be the galois group of the splitting field $E$ of $f$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. How to show that $G$ contains a profuct of disjoint $r$ cycles of length $d_1,...d_r$.

I tried this problem using algebraic number theory techniques. I considered a prime ideal $P$ of $E$ above $p$ and tried to work with $Frob(P/p)$ but nothing worked out. Please help...

Comment: That is how you should be thinking. Since $f \bmod p$ is separable (why?) $p$ will be unramified and the roots of $f$ in $\mathcal O_E$ will be *distinct* when reduced mod $P$. So the action of the Frobenius element at $P$ as a permutation of the roots in $E$ will match its action on the roots when they are reduced mod $P$. Then relate the fact that the Frobenius element is, on the residue field at $P$, the $p$th power map to Galois theory of finite fields in order to get the cycle structure of the Frobenius action on the roots mod $P$ from the irreducible factorization of $f \bmod p$.

Comment: Why should the roots of $f$ be distinct mod $P$?

Comment: That's what I asked "why?" when I said $f \bmod p$ is separable. The field $\mathcal O_E/P$ is an extension of $\mathbf Z/(p)$.

Comment: Why should $f$ mod $p$ be separable?